# GETTING listboxitems from other thread: Cross-thread operation not valid

Tags: c#

So far I have seen 1000 examples how to set items in listbox objects from a different thread using the Invoke method.

However, I cannot find any solution on how to simply read the items from a listbox from a background worker tread. How do I invoke this before reading the SelectedItems for example...

```
foreach (var item in CheckedListBox1.SelectedItems)
{
 //Do something
}
```

Above code running in the background worker generated the following error:

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'CheckedListBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may similarly use `Invoke` to *read* UI elements from a background thread:

```
var selectedItems = (IList)this.Invoke(new Func<IList>(() =>
    CheckedListBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<object>().ToList()));

foreach (var item in selectedItems)
{
    //Do something
}
```

If you know the type of your items, you may specify the type in the `Cast` call, and return an `IList<YourType>` rather than the non-generic `IList`.

Comment: tnx.. However it give me the following error: System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<TResult>(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context. It gives this at Cast<object>

Comment: @user1434880: My apologies, I missed the parentheses after the `Cast`. Try using the updated code.

Comment: Perfect.. That works.. (only one missing parenthese at the end.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a reference to a UI object. Then you can use this code (.NET 4.0) to invoke stuff on the main thread when you don't have a reference, as you can use the Application.Current Pointer which is on the main thread:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
{
    // TODO: Implement task to do on main thread
    foreach (var item in CheckedListBox1.SelectedItems)
    {
         //Do something
    }
});
```